# Matching log entries across multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering how I approach matching log entries that might span multiple lines in a text file, specifically using python.

```
[yyyy/mm/dd time] Entry
[yyyy/mm/dd time] this is
a multiline
entry
[yyyy/mm/dd time] Another entry
```

So my regex in this scenario should have 3 matches.

At best, I have a regex that matches each line, but this one falls short when it comes to log entries split across multiple lines:

```
regex = re.compile(\[\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}.{31}].*')
```

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/aaNtXs

Comment: multiline = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your lines and check for a match - if a match is found, add a new log entry, if not append the line to the previously captured log, i.e.:

```
LINE_START = re.compile(r"\[\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}")  # etc.

with open("path/to/your.log", "r") as f:
    log_lines = [next(f)]  # a list to hold the log lines, initiate with the first line
    for line in f:
        if LINE_START.match(line):  # a new log line found
            log_lines.append("")  # 'register' a new log entry
        log_lines[-1] += line  # append the line to the last log entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.S` and `re.MULTILINE` to make dots match newlines and to use `^` to match linestarts.

Then, match everything between two timestamps or between a timestamp and the end of the string.

```
regex = re.compile("^\[\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}[^\]]*](.*?)(?=^\[\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}[^\]]*])|^\[\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}[^\]]*](.*?)(?!.)",re.S | re.MULTILINE)
```

test: https://regex101.com/r/dR25vY/2